# How to get the queryparam vid from the url using regex

Tags: regex

Help me with the regex, I am trying to get the vid value from the following [url](http://gorid.com/api.jsp?acs=123&vid=432&skey=asdasd-asdas-adsasd&gvid=12asasass).

I tried with like the following but I am not sure with that:

```
[\&]{1}vid[\=][\d]*
```

Is that correct?

Comment: What tool/language are you using?  Probably you can just take advantage of a URL parser in the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tim, I am just checking with the regex101.com

Comment: How about this: `vid=(.*?)&`

Comment: why not vid=(\d+) ?

Comment: OK but you must have a target application for this...you can just find that query parameter by looking at the URL.

Comment: It's a rule check in the middle ware, not parsing with the app

Comment: I provided a valid answer below. Using vid=(.*?)& will not acheive what you want because:  
1. It will also return the string "vid=".  
2. It will be greedy and give you all the character uo to the last instance of & in the string.

Comment: @Nadav, vid is a number, can you please add number checj

Comment: @Nadav url, updated can you please check once again

Comment: I edited my answer, added more information and also offered a regex that includes the required numbers-only check.

Answer (score 1):

Use vid=(\d+) for numbers of IDs see [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ev7jd1/5)

Comment: I updated the url, can you please take a look, because it is matching two queryparams

Comment: it's capturing '&' also. how to skip that

Comment: remove & see link

Comment: I didn't see the check to capture the first vid not to gVID value

Comment: Site add / at start of the regex by default

Answer (score 0):

Try Your Regex on this place...
https://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4/1

Comment: What you want me to ]do with this?

Comment: You can set your define regex in this url

Comment: What you are checking even...please make a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

The regex you wrote will not work because you are including the characters &vid= in the return value. To make sure the regex engine checks for the string &vid= but does not include it in the result you will need to use a lookbehind:

`(?<=&vid=)([^&\r\n]+)`

We use a positive lookbehind to find `&vid=` and then grab everything from that point until the next & sign or the end of the line.

For your second request, if you wish to verify that the content of `vid` is a valid number you need to specify that all the characters following `&vid=` should be digits and also include a positive lookahead that makes sure the next character after the digits is a & sign. The corresponding regular expression then becomes:

`(?<=&vid=)([^\D]+)(?=&)`

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to match between two patterns of interest -

1. "vid="
2. "&"

Anything you capture between that is what you're after.

Hence use this:

```
"http://gorid.com/api.jsp?acs=123&vid=432&skey=asdasd-asdas-adsasd".match("vid=([^;]*)&")[1]
```

We're accessing the 2nd element of the match object because that contains the value.

Answer (score 0):

In a JS/PHP type environment, you can match on something like this, where you just find anything alphanumeric is between `vid=` and the following `&`:

```
vv = str.match(/vid=(.+?)&/)[1];
```

[HERE](https://regex101.com/r/9XpAYP/1)

If the value is always numeric, replace `(.+?)` with `(\d+?)`